# Automating complex refactoring tasks

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, refactoring

I have the situation that the same repeating refactoring tasks have to be done for a huge number of methods in my code.
For example imagine a interface with 100 methods, each of them has one or more parameters as well as a return value. For each of these methods I need to jump to the implementation change the return type and add a line of code which converts the old return value to its new type for callers of the interface method.

Is there any way to quickly automate such refactorings?
I even thought to write a custom script to do it, but writing a intelligent script would approximately take longer than doing it maually.

A tool supporting such task can save a lot of time.

Comment: I feel pain when I imagine an interface with 100 methods.

Comment: It's just an example, but think of a WCF Service Contract...not that unimaginable

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question, but in the time it took since you posted it (not to mention the time you spent searching for an answer before posting), you could have completed the changes manually.

I know, I know, it's utterly unsatisfying, but if you think of it as a form of mediation, and only do this once a year, it's not that bad.

Comment: Doing it manually took me 3 days. 3 days of monkey-doing. Thats a waste of money.

Comment: Indeed, unless you had monkeys do it... Anyway, without seeing the actual modifications you had to do, it's hard to give any concrete advice. Perhaps some regular expression find-n-replace would have done most of the work, leaving you with a couple of hours of manual labor. It's too vague.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is *one* interface with 100 methods, then I agree with another poster: just doing it may seem painful but it is limited in effort and you can be done really soon.

If you have this problem repeatedly, or you have very large code base (many, many interfaces for which you want to perform this task), then what you need is a tool for implementing automated change: a [program transformation engine](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html).   Such a tool provides the ability to parse source code, build a program representation (an abstract syntax tree), and enables one to apply "scripted" operations on the tree either through procedural interfaces and/or through source-to-source transformation patterns.

OUr [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is such a program transformation system.  It has a [C# Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CSharpFrontEnd.html) to enable its application to C# code.  Configuring such a tool for a complex task is not a matter of hours, so it is not useful for "small scale" changes.  For large scale changes, such tools can make it possible to do things simply not practical by hand.

Answer (score 0):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and [CodeRush](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) both have features which can help with this kind of task.

Resharper's [change signature](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Change_Signature) functionality is probably the closest match.

Comment: No neigter ReSharoper nor CodeRush can do something like this fully automatic without user interaction. You still need to do it manually for each method.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood the question. Could you combine that with a macro? Go to method definition > Change signiture > go to end of method > paste > repeat?

Comment: ^^ That's exactly what i need. But i don't know how to do this without great expense

Answer (score 0):

Can't you generate a new interface from the class you have and then remove the ones you don't need! if it's that simple!!

Comment: Normally you would do this yes. But if you also need to add add view lines of code here, remove some there...?

Answer (score 0):

change the return type : by changing... the return type, provided it is not a standard type (...), and the converter can be implemented by a TypeConverter.

When i have such boring task to do, i often switch VS2010 and use a tool that allow regex search and replace. In your example, maybe change 'return xxx;' by 'var yyy=convert(xxx); return yyy;'

(for example editor Notepad++ (free) allready offers quite some possiblities to change everything in a project (use with caution))